# What does the phrase 'inner necessity' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In this following context, what does the phrase 'inner necessity' mean?

How should I understand this sentence easily and simply?

Context:

> “Cause” refers really to that thing which — if all the necessary
> conditions are present — by inner necessity is in time followed by
> another thing as its “result,” so that already in the cause the future
> result is lying latent, as it were, just as in the mango seed the
> future mango tree lies latent.

Source: P. 31
''Fundamentals of Buddhism''
by Nyanatiloka Mahåthera

Comment: Do you know what "necessity" means? "Inner" is referring to something that relates to the essential properties of the objects involved, rather than being a result of external forces. It's hard to explain this in simple language, because it is a technical philosophical concept.

Comment: *“Cause” refers to that which **perforce** is followed by its “result".* Doesn't look very "technical" to me. This trivial observation can be manifest and/or described with various different nuances: *Nothing is ever truly random. Actions have consequences. To every action there is an equal and opposite reaction. Everything is connected, What goes up must come down...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers -'inner necessity' sounds like hocus-pocus to me.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I doubt Nyanatiloka Mahåthera was a native Anglophone. His mother tongue was probably German, but ''Fundamentals of Buddhism'' was a series of 4 lectures, quite possibly delivered in some Indian language. We're definitely looking at a *translation*, whatever the "original" language was. But the intended sense should be obvious anyway, given the example of a seed which ***inherently*** leads to a tree in the fullness of time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - yes, my 'hocus pocus' was directed at the idea that the universe is deterministic. I don't think it is.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I think the jury is still out as regards whether the universe as a whole (and thus by implication, every quantum level event *within* it, for all time) is "deterministic". But for all practical purposes, ***causes have effects*** - one thing leads to another, so if you currently have "one thing" then you sorta have "another" as well (or at least, *will* have, in due course).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - well, OK. I have trouble seeing (for example) how an individual photon is 'destined' to go through one of the two slits in the well-know experiment. I guess my approach has to follow Feynman's 'just do the math' (as far as I able, which is not very).

Comment: I'm not sure it means much to suggest an individual photon might be 'destined' to take one path over another. So far as I'm aware, that 'individual' photon doesn't really *exist* anyway - unless and until the observer makes a measurement that *forces* it to be somewhere, or to take some specific path, that photon is kinda "smeared out" across the entire universe (it's just that if you try to pin it down, it's more *likely* to be in one place rather than another). I can't do the maths either - but some people can, and apparently it does work (in a wide range of technological applications).